# Tensorflow 1.0 Windows + 64-bit Anaconda 4.3.0 error

Tags: tensorflow

Following the instructions under "Installing with Anaconda" at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows, I get to this point and get a failure.

`(tensorflow) C:\Users\rallen\Documents\Devel\python\tensorflow>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

This is my environment 64-bit Anaconda3 4.3.0

`>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

I previously successfully installed pre-1.0 tensorflow from pip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently python 3.5 is very important.  Since the latest Anaconda3 distribution is 3.6, you have to do this:

`> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`

and it seems the 1.0 package is available on pip now, so you can just do this:

`..> activate tensorflow
...> pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (43.1MB)
    100% |################################| 43.1MB 31kB/s
Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
...`

I've successfully run the 'hello world' commands in the python 3.5 shell and `tf.__version__` shows as `'1.0.0'`

Comment: I am getting this error:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl` will fail but `tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd_64.whl` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

For who using python version 3.6 and anaconda.

```html
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7552), maybe `win_x86_64` should be changed to `win_amd64`

Answer (score 0):

**1) C:>pip uninstall tensorflow 

2) C:>pip install tensorflow**

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Miniconda(Anaconda). I have used pycharm in which I have added the Miniconda(Anaconda) interpreter. TensorFlow can be easily added through this interpreter by searching for the required `TensorFlow` package

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue yesterday with command
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl

simply write

> C:>pip install tensorflow
>
> C:>pip install tensorflow-gpu #for gpu version

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and this snipped should work for most of people.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Because I have install tensorflow version 0.12 before, it will use cache, so I have to specify the version to be 1.0

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0
```

It's worked well for me!!

I'm working on win10 with python version=3.5.2, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem when I installed anaconda 4.3 version

"tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Here is my solution.

- Instead of using Anaconda3 4.3, install Anaconda3 4.2(Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)
- Type on command line(If you are using GPU version)

  ```
  pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  ```
- Typeon command line(If you are using CPU only)

  ```
  pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  ```

I'm working on win10 with python version=3.5.2, 64 bit